# looping element into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a list of the unique remainders for the number 99 divided by the powers of 2 (2,4,8,16,32,64) which are lower then that of 99.
here is the code:

```
num = 99
div = 2
lst = []

while div < num:
    r = num % div
    while r != 0 and r not in lst:
        lst.append(r)
    div = div * div
print(lst)`
```

The code I use doesn't append the remainder for the 99 % 64 in the list, which is 35.
program output:
[1,3]

intended output:
[1,3,35]

I am a complete beginner in programming, I would appreciate if you can help me find out the correct approach for the problem I have.

Comment: if I am not wrong, in the loop, div is getting: 2->2*2=4->4*4=16->16*16=256, but I think it should be getting 2->2^2=4->2^3=8->2^4=16->2^5->32->... Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: To get the sequence of *div* values you should just multiply by 2 upon each iteration

Comment: you are right, I didn't even think about that. how should I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `div` is incrementing in each step as

```
0 ->2
1 -> 4 # 2*2
2 -> 16 # 4*4
3 -> 256 # 16 * 16
```

here in step/loop 3, value of `div` is more than `num`, ie 256 > 99 , hence program end in `while` loop and thus
exit, and your output become `[1, 3]` only

to solve this, you need to increase value of `div` by multiple of 2. Below is code for you

```
>>> num = 99
>>> div = 2
>>> lst = []
>>> while div < num:
...     r = num%div
...     while r!=0 and r not in lst:
...             lst.append(r)
...     div = div *2
... 
>>> print(lst)
[1, 3, 35]
```

little better performance code here isd for you wutgh using set

```
>>> num = 99
>>> div = 2
>>> lst = set()
>>> 
>>> while div < num:
...     r = num%div
...     lst.add(r)
...     div = div*2
... 
>>> lst
{1, 3, 35}
>>> print(list(lst))
[1, 3, 35]
>>>
```

using set comprehension

```
from math import log, ceil
num = 99
result =  {num%(2**i) for i in range(1, ceil(log(num, 2)))}
print(result)
# {1,3,35}
```

using set comprehension using dict property as order is metained there

```
from math import log, ceil
num = 99
result =  {num%(2**i): 1 for i in range(1, ceil(log(num, 2)))}
print(result.keys())
# dict_keys([1, 3, 35]) # use list(result.keys()) to get output in list
```

Comment: I suggest second `while` should more correctly be `if`

Comment: @user19077881 dont even need this, just make `lst` to set and do `lst.add(r)` , and it will remove all duplicates and operation will be o(1), just kept this way to keep OP code as OP has written

Comment: It could also be done in a one-liner using set comprehension.

Comment: @user19077881 added set comprehension solution also :D

Comment: The output values happen to be in the correct order but this is not a general solution. The set would need to be sorted to ensure the required output

Comment: @DarkKnight you are right, we can use ordereddict for this to maintain order, and dont need to use sort method

Answer (score 1):

### Your way

Add a variable to keep track of the power and increment it in each loop:

```py
num = 99
div = 2
power = 1
lst = []

while div < num:
    r = num % div
    while r != 0 and r not in lst:
        lst.append(r)
    power += 1 # Increment the power variable
    div = div ** up # Double asterisks is for the power operation
    print(div)
print(lst)
```

### Another way

You can do it also in a more pythonic way.

- First line, returns a list with all powers of 2 lower than 99
- Second line, maps each element to its remainders, converts it to the datatype *set* (to keep all unique elements), and finally converts it to list.

```py
a = [x for x in [2**p for p in range(1, 11)] if x < 99]
a = list(set(map(lambda x : 99 % x, a)))
print(a)
```

I would not suggest putting it all in one line *like below* because you lose readability.

```py
a = list(set(map(lambda x : 99 % x, [x for x in [2**p for p in range(1, 11)] if x < 99]))) # Don't do it
```

Answer (score 1):

You should build your collection of unique values in a set. Finally sort the set to give the output as required

```
num = 99
unique = set()
div = 2

while div < num:
    unique.add(num%div)
    div *= 2

print(sorted(unique))
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 3, 35]
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, overcomplicating it is the best way to get really lost really quickly.

```
num = 99 
div = 2
power = 1
lst = []

while div < num:              # We only care about div values less than num
    div = div**power          # This incrementally raises div to the power exponent
    power += 1                # This will increment power by + 1 for each loop, other useful iterative operators are [-=,*=]
    lst.append(num % div)     # 'Appends*' the remainder of num/div to lst (*will add to the list without caring too much about index)
print(lst)                    # Prints the list
```

This will also print 99 as it trys to find the remainder of 128 as well, but that might be a fun challenge for you to figure out if you're trying to learn d:

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not generate the required output